# Using squidview to see users abusing the network right now

Tags: squid

We have a Squid 2.6 server running on Ubuntu 8.04. We have an SNMP monitoring software (Zabbix) that gives us almost real time graphs of our internet connection.

I have tried to use squidview to see who is abusing the network, but the "tally" mode always starts checking the log from the beginning of the logfile.

If I understood correctly, I can move to a later line in the log, and start "tally" mode from there, but it's not working. It starts from the top anyway.

Any ideas? Any other options for finding bandwidth hogs in "real time"? (it's never really real time, but close to it is enough)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was fixed after upgrading to Ubuntu 10.04 64bits.
Now squidview works fine.

Here is what I do:

- Start squidview
- Press 'g' and enter 100 (it will take you to the last line of access.log)
- Press 'T' and it will enter Tally mode from the point where you are. It should be "real-time", and in a few seconds it will have at the top the biggest offenders.

I'm still having some trouble, in which the left-most column does not show complete IP addresses, but so far it's not been critical.

Comment: I've got the incomplete IP issue too.. did you resolve it?

Comment: Nevermind, entered common options 'c', set width with 'w' to 15.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using Free-SA to generate reports on your squid logs

http://free-sa.sourceforge.net/

Not exactly realtime, but you can run it on the fly and it will give you better reporting than squidview.

Comment: I'm already using SARG for reports, generating them nightly. So we do get the chance to talk to abusers the next day and "educate" them. But we need something faster than that. Squidview is supposed to be able to give "tally" for the position in the log file that you are viewing, but I can't get it to work. If I could, I can calculate it for the last 10 minutes, for example. This is SARG: http://sarg.sourceforge.net/

Comment: then why not use free-sa / sarg on a tail -1000 of the squid log file every x minutes or similar

Comment: That's actually not a bad idea at all. I'll probably use it at some point. Thanks!